# Stationarity of a variable measured at irregular intervals

Tags: regression, time-series, stationarity, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I have data collected on a meeting-by-meeting basis, where the change in time between two meetings is not constant, i.e., $\Delta t\ne1$. Are ordinary Augmented Dicky Fuller and Phillips-Perron tests valid in this context?

Comment: This is an interesting question, but note that duration models usually have (deterministically) time-varying parameters already. You might want to tell us more about what data you are collecting at irregular intervals, what process you want to use to model it, and what parameters you want to allow to be time-varying.

Comment: I am estimating a central bank reaction function. The central bank might meet in January, March, April (due to an unexpected shock), July etc. The data are typical macro variables (output, prices, share prices etc). I have collected data on each of these variables for the meeting in question. Therefore, when checking for stationarity, the interval between observations is not constant. Note that I cannot test the data before assigning it to a meeting as the particular data is only available at a meeting-by-meeting frequency